# CMake 2.8.12 building for windows phone 8

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, cmake

Is there any way to generate VS 2012 Windows phone 8 solutions using CMake 2.8.12? I have tried all possibile combinations including generating an NMake Makefile and they all seem to fail miserably.

Can I build my CMake project targeting ARM for windows phone at all or its impossible at this time?

Thanks
Sundar

Comment: Please check this guide: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/uk_faculty_connection/archive/2014/07/29/cmake-for-windows-store-and-windows-phone-apps.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft and Kitware have enabled CMake support for Windows Phone and Windows Store apps. http://cmakems.codeplex.com/ Very soon, the contribution will be available in the official CMake repository as well